# How to change default flask logger output to an json logging handler

Tags: python-3.x, logging, flask

i need to change flask default logging handler to a custom JSON logging text, i can change handler before app.run() but flask set a default handler when I don't a standard handler (clear() logging handlers)

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled over a very convenient way to solve this challenge.

Go for json-logging package (https://github.com/bobbui/json-logging-python)

With that package installed, it's as easy as that:

```
import datetime, logging, sys, json_logging, flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
json_logging.init_flask(enable_json=True)
json_logging.init_request_instrument(app)
```

And proceed as usual in your Flask app.

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
from pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger import JsonFormatter

def get_logger(module_name):
    """Generate a logger."""
    logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
    # logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.propagate = False    # reset handler to avoid duplicates
    logger.handlers = [get_json_handler()]
    return logger


def get_json_handler():
    """Generate a JsonFormatter"""
    formatter = JsonFormatter("(asctime) (levelname) (module) (funcName) (lineno) (message)")
    log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    return log_handler

# Example:
log = get_logger()

flask_log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
flask_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
flask_log.addHandler(log)
```